# Why does SoundPlayer intermittently hang on playback?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, audio, directshow.net

I have a WPF application in which I'm using `SoundPlayer` to play several short sounds such as keyboard clicks. Sometimes, seemingly at random, the sounds will stop playing. When I navigate away from the page the sounds will then play all at once in one screeching playback.

My question is, are there any obvious reasons as to why this would happen?

I've tried several things but because I can't consistently reproduce the issue it's hard to find the cause. The sounds are used throughout the application, so I load them in app.xaml.cs into an application scoped static collection. I call `SoundPlayer.Load()` to ensure they're loaded into memory straight away.

Like I said, this never stops working completely. The play backs seem to pile up until navigating to another page where they all play at once.

One other thing that may have an impact is that I am displaying a webcam feed in the application. The webcam feed is loaded using the DirectShow.NET library. I'm not sure if loading graphs can have any adverse effect on the playback of sound.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the web cam is updating a UI element which will cause the UI thread to be pretty busy, in that case you probably do not want to use `SoundPlayer.PlaySync()` or `SoundPlayer.Load` which both block the current thread.

Instead try `SoundPlayer.LoadAsync()` and `SoundPlayer.Play()` which use a separate thread.

Comment: I just gave that a try and you also made me realise my misuse of `SoundPlayer.Load()` in conjunction with `SoundPlayer.Play()` - one is for sync the other async. I was already unknowingly playing them in a separate thread. Adding `SoundPlayer.LoadAsync()` hasn't fixed the problem. 
I did an experiment to load and play the sounds synchronously. This actually caused the application to hang and not respond when the sound issue was encountered, presumably because the thread is now waiting on something and refuses to continue.

Comment: did you try and stop the web cam feed to see if it is directly related to that?

Comment: I did stop the feed and couldn't recreate the sound issues. I don't know if this is a direct relation or if there is another common element involved.